# Update Laravel Eloquent ORM with array

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to figure out how to update and Eloquent ORM modal from an array. Rather than going field by field. This is what I have so far.

```
public static function updatePatient($id){
    $patient_payload = Input::all();  // eg. array('patient_first_name'=>'Test', 'patient_last_name'=>'TEST')
    $patient_to_update = Patient::find($id);

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Validate the request
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    if(!$patient_to_update)
        return Response::json(array('error'=>'No patient found for id given'), 400);

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Update the patient entry.
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */


    $patient_to_update->update($patient_payload);
    $patient_to_update->save();

    return Response::json(array('success'=>'Patient was updated'));
}
```

This throws a laravel model error just saying: 'patient_first_name' and yes, patient_first_name is a col on the db. As a work around I have just been doing this, which works.

```
public static function updatePatient($id){
    $patient_payload = Input::all();
    $patient_to_update = Patient::find($id);

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Validate the request
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    if(!$patient_to_update)
        return Response::json(array('error'=>'No patient found for id given'), 400);

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Update the patient entry. 
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */


    DB::table('patients')
        ->where('id',$id)
        ->update($patient_payload);

    //update laravel timestamps
    $patient_to_update->touch();        
    return Response::json(array('success'=>'Patient was updated'));
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you are trying to do is mass assignment, I'd suggest to check if you have defined the `$fillable` property in your `Patient` model:

```
class Patient extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('patient_payload');

}
```

As a security measure, Eloquent will not allow you to modify any model's attributes via mass assignment unless you specify [`$fillable`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#1561-1572) (white list of allowed attributes) or [`$guarded`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#107-112) (black list of forbidden attributes).

---

Further reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_assignment_vulnerability

Comment: That's great this works. I whitelisted fields with $guarded. Great that laravel protects against mass assignment by default.